# Is the UNIVERSE trying to discover itself?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science

We are all made of atoms. We are trying to discover the universe(which is made up of atoms) . So can I say the universe is trying to Discover itself?

Comment: Can you share a little more about what you might have been reading or studying that's made this concern an interesting or important one to you? What exactly are you looking for someone here to explain to you? (This doesn't feel like a particularly specific concern arising from the study of philosophy as currently framed.)

Comment: Mr. Joseph, 
I came across a sentence- "Biology is nothing but physics and chemistry applied."
If it is so, then the same atoms make both the universe and us(living things). We know that we are a part of the universe. Till now it has not been able to describe what 'living' means.
So, i wanted to know if my thoughts are correct and also how many people share this thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property of a part is not necessarily a property of the whole. For example, a page in a book has a page number, but the book itself does not have a page number.

In your example, the fact that we (the part) have a property (the intention of discovery) does not imply that the whole (the universe) has that property too.

I should add to this the fact that intentions need agency. And I would dispute strongly that the universe, as such, has it.

Answer (score 2):

Humanity is not identical to the universe (universe is way bigger), although we are a part of it. So you can say: A little part of the universe is trying to discover the universe.

Answer (score 0):

@CesarGon, I think OP clearly didn't described our atoms and the universe atoms as seperated, you did a seperation which is not clearly logical and proven here, ( - what made you seperate people from the universe atoms? - who said it's not one? - what are you RELYING on?)

in the case that our atoms and the universe atoms are one, (I'm not saying it is but I'm also not saying it's not), and by your logical statements, clearly OP is right.